# forward motion car physics - gradual slow

Tags: physics, xna-4.0

Im having trouble creating realistic car movements in xna 4.
Right now i have a car going forward and hitting a terminal velocity which is fine but when i release the up key i need to the car to slow down gradually and then come to a stop.
Im pretty sure this is easy code but i cant seem to get it to work

the code - update

```
if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            {
                double elapsedTime = gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
                CalcTotalForce();
                Acceleration = Vector2.Divide(CalcTotalForce(), MASS);
                Velocity = Vector2.Add(Velocity, Vector2.Multiply(Acceleration, (float)(elapsedTime)));
                Position = Vector2.Add(Position, Vector2.Multiply(Velocity, (float)(elapsedTime)));
            }
```

added functions

```
public Vector2 CalcTraction()
    {
        //Traction force = vector direction * engine force
        return Vector2.Multiply(forwardDirection, ENGINE_FORCE);
    }
        public Vector2 CalcDrag()
        {
            //Drag force = constdrag * velocity * speed
            return Vector2.Multiply(Vector2.Multiply(Velocity, DRAG_CONST), Velocity.Y);
        }

        public Vector2 CalcRoll()
        {
            //roll force = const roll * velocity
            return Vector2.Multiply(Velocity, ROLL_CONST);
        }

        public Vector2 CalcTotalForce()
        {
            //total force = traction + (-drag) + (-rolling)
            return Vector2.Add(CalcTraction(), 
                Vector2.Add(-CalcDrag(), -CalcRoll()));
        }
```

anyone have any ideas?

Comment: you answered your own question about how to fix your own code.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple:

Take Position out of the keyboard method and have it at the end of the update function.
then add to "on key up" call a deceleration vector. i.e

```
 if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            {
                Acceleration = Vector2.Divide(CalcTotalForce(), MASS);
                Velocity = Vector2.Add(Velocity, Vector2.Multiply(Acceleration, (float)(elapsedTime)));
            }
            else if(Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyUp(Keys.Up))
            {
                if (Velocity.Y < 0)
                    Velocity = Vector2.Add(Velocity, Vector2.Multiply(decceleration, (float)(elapsedTime)));
            }
```